# How to add text on multiple lines next to a down arrow

Tags: math-mode

```
$$\qquad \qquad \qquad \bigg\downarrow \text{\small some text here\\ I would like this part to go on a new line}$$
```

gives me this

[image]

Since the text is so long, I would like for part of it to be on a new line. Is this possible? I tried using `\\` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use \parbox

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[  
    \qquad \qquad \qquad \bigg\downarrow \parbox{5cm}{\tiny some text here\\ I would like this \\ part to go on a new line}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text inside a `tabular` (which defaults to using text mode for the contents) and use an extensibly (`\left` or `\right`) `\downarrow` to scale the arrow to fit your vertical length:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left\downarrow
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
    \small some text here \\
    \small I would like this part to go on a new line
  \end{tabular}
  \right.
\]

\[
  \left\downarrow
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
    \small some text here \\
    \small I would like this part to go on a new line \\
    \small and this is down even further
  \end{tabular}
  \right.
\]

\end{document}
```